# SQL query is taking very long time using in EBS

Tags: performance, oracle11gr2

I have select query below and it is taking long time for only one org_id=83 only don't know why?

can you please help me on this? Please let me know if you need more details on this?

I am using Oracle 11.2.1 version.

```
SELECT a.customer_trx_id                                      CUSTOMER_TRX_ID, 
       a.trx_number                                           TRX_NUMBER, 
       Nvl(TL.sequence_num, 1) 
       TERM_SEQUENCE_NUMBER, 
       types.TYPE                                             TRX_TYPE, 
       l_types.meaning                                        TRX_TYPE_NAME, 
       TYPES.accounting_affect_flag 
       OPEN_RECEIVABLE_FLAG, 
       a.trx_date                                             TRX_DATE, 
       ship_to_customer_id 
       SHIP_TO_CUSTOMER_ID, 
       ship_to_contact_id                                     SHIP_TO_CONTACT_ID 
       , 
       remit_to_address_id 
       REMIT_TO_ADDRESS_ID, 
       A.primary_salesrep_id 
       PRIMARY_SALESREP_ID, 
       B.account_number                                       CUSTOMER_NUMBER, 
       A.internal_notes                                       INTERNAL_NOTES, 
       A.batch_source_id                                      BATCH_SOURCE_ID, 
       A.comments                                             TRX_COMMENTS, 
       previous_customer_trx_id 
       PREVIOUS_CUSTOMER_TRX_ID, 
       ship_to_site_use_id 
       SHIP_TO_SITE_USE_ID, 
       Nvl(printing_count, 0)                                 PRINTING_COUNT, 
       printing_original_date 
       PRINTING_ORIGINAL_DATE, 
       printing_last_printed 
       PRINTING_LAST_PRINTED, 
       printing_pending                                       PRINTING_PENDING, 
       last_printed_sequence_num 
       LAST_PRINTED_SEQUENCE_NUMBER, 
       start_date_commitment 
       START_DATE_COMMITMENT, 
       end_date_commitment 
       END_DATE_COMMITMENT, 
       initial_customer_trx_id 
       INITIAL_CUSTOMER_TRX_ID, 
       A.invoice_currency_code 
       INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE, 
       A.term_id                                              TERM_ID, 
       A.ship_date_actual                                     SHIP_DATE_ACTUAL, 
       A.ship_via                                             SHIP_VIA, 
       A.waybill_number                                       WAYBILL_NUMBER, 
       A.purchase_order 
       PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER, 
       A.purchase_order_revision 
       PURCHASE_ORDER_REVISION, 
       A.purchase_order_date 
       PURCHASE_ORDER_DATE, 
       P.due_date 
       TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS, 
       Nvl(TL.relative_amount, 100) * ( 100 / Nvl(T.base_amount, 100) ) 
       TERM_RELATIVE_AMOUNT, 
       T.name                                                 TERM_NAME, 
       A.bill_to_customer_id 
       BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID, 
       A.bill_to_contact_id                                   BILL_TO_CONTACT_ID 
       , 
       A.bill_to_site_use_id 
       BILL_TO_SITE_USE_ID, 
       U_BILL.location                                        BILL_TO_LOCATION, 
       Nvl(A_BILL.translated_customer_name, PARTY.party_name) BILL_CUST_NAME, 
       Rtrim(Rpad(LOC.address1, 40))                          BILL_ADDRESS1, 
       Rtrim(Rpad(LOC.address2, 40))                          BILL_ADDRESS2, 
       Rtrim(Rpad(LOC.address3, 40))                          BILL_ADDRESS3, 
       Rtrim(Rpad(LOC.address4, 40))                          BILL_ADDRESS4, 
       LOC.city                                               BILL_CITY, 
       Nvl(LOC.state, LOC.province)                           BILL_STATE, 
       LOC.postal_code                                        BILL_POSTAL_CODE, 
       LOC.country                                            BILL_COUNTRY, 
       U_BILL.tax_reference 
       BILL_SITE_TAX_REFERENCE, 
       PARTY.tax_reference 
       BILL_CUST_TAX_REFERENCE, 
       Nvl(amount_line_items_original, To_number(NULL))       TRX_LINE_AMOUNT, 
       Nvl(tax_original, To_number(NULL))                     TRX_TAX_AMOUNT, 
       Nvl(freight_original, To_number(NULL))                 TRX_FREIGHT_AMOUNT 
       , 
       p.amount_due_original 
       TRX_ALL_AMOUNT, 
       A.trx_number                                           ORDER_BY, 
       LOC.address1                                           BILL_TO_ADDRESS1, 
       LOC.address2                                           BILL_TO_ADDRESS2, 
       LOC.address3                                           BILL_TO_ADDRESS3, 
       LOC.address4                                           BILL_TO_ADDRESS4, 
       LOC.state                                              BILL_TO_STATE, 
       LOC.province                                           BILL_TO_PROVINCE 
FROM   ar_adjustments COM_ADJ, 
       ar_payment_schedules P, 
       ra_cust_trx_line_gl_dist REC, 
       ra_customer_trx A, 
       hz_cust_accounts B, 
       ra_terms T, 
       ra_terms_lines TL, 
       ra_cust_trx_types TYPES, 
       ar_lookups L_TYPES, 
       hz_parties PARTY, 
       hz_cust_acct_sites A_BILL, 
       hz_party_sites PARTY_SITE, 
       hz_locations LOC, 
       hz_cust_site_uses U_BILL 
WHERE  A.bill_to_customer_id = B.cust_account_id 
       AND REC.customer_trx_id = A.customer_trx_id 
       AND REC.latest_rec_flag = 'Y' 
       AND REC.account_class = 'REC' 
       AND P.payment_schedule_id + Decode(P.class, 'INV', 0, '') = COM_ADJ.payment_schedule_id(+) 
       AND COM_ADJ.subsequent_trx_id IS NULL 
       AND 'C' = COM_ADJ.adjustment_type(+) 
       AND A.complete_flag = 'Y' 
       AND A.cust_trx_type_id = TYPES.cust_trx_type_id 
       AND L_TYPES.lookup_type = 'INV/CM/ADJ' 
       AND A.printing_option IN ( 'PRI', 'REP' ) 
       AND L_TYPES.lookup_code = Decode(TYPES.TYPE, 'DEP', 'INV', 
                                                    TYPES.TYPE) 
       AND Nvl(P.terms_sequence_number, Nvl(TL.sequence_num, 0)) = 
           Nvl(TL.sequence_num, Nvl(p.terms_sequence_number, 0)) 
       AND Decode(P.payment_schedule_id, '', 0, 
                                         Nvl(T.printing_lead_days, 0)) = 0 
       AND A.bill_to_site_use_id = U_BILL.site_use_id 
       AND U_BILL.cust_acct_site_id = A_BILL.cust_acct_site_id 
       AND A_BILL.party_site_id = party_site.party_site_id 
       AND B.party_id = PARTY.party_id 
       AND loc.location_id = party_site.location_id 
       AND Nvl(LOC.LANGUAGE, 'US') = 'US' 
       AND Nvl(P.amount_due_remaining, 0) <> 0 
       AND A.term_id = TL.term_id(+) 
       AND A.term_id = T.term_id(+) 
       AND A.customer_trx_id = P.customer_trx_id(+) 
       AND A.printing_pending = 'Y' 
       AND Nvl(TL.sequence_num, 1) > Nvl(A.last_printed_sequence_num, 0) 
       AND Nvl(LOC.LANGUAGE, 'US') = 'US' 
       AND NOT EXISTS 
       (SELECT 'X' 
           FROM   ece_tp_details ETD, 
                  ece_tp_headers ETH 
           WHERE  ETH.tp_header_id = A_BILL.tp_header_id 
                  AND ETD.tp_header_id = ETH.tp_header_id 
                  AND ETD.edi_flag = 'Y' 
                  AND ETD.document_id = 'INO' 
                  AND ETD.document_type = Decode (TYPES.TYPE, 'CM',Decode(A.previous_customer_trx_id, NULL, 'OACM', 'CM'), TYPES.TYPE)) 
UNION 
SELECT a.customer_trx_id, 
       a.trx_number, 
       Nvl(P.terms_sequence_number, 1), 
       types.TYPE, 
       l_types.meaning, 
       TYPES.accounting_affect_flag, 
       a.trx_date, 
       A.ship_to_customer_id, 
       A.ship_to_contact_id, 
       A.remit_to_address_id, 
       A.primary_salesrep_id, 
       B.account_number, 
       A.internal_notes, 
       A.batch_source_id, 
       A.comments, 
       previous_customer_trx_id, 
       ship_to_site_use_id, 
       Nvl(printing_count, 0), 
       printing_original_date, 
       printing_last_printed, 
       printing_pending, 
       last_printed_sequence_num, 
       start_date_commitment, 
       end_date_commitment, 
       initial_customer_trx_id, 
       A.invoice_currency_code, 
       A.term_id, 
       A.ship_date_actual, 
       A.ship_via, 
       A.waybill_number, 
       A.purchase_order, 
       A.purchase_order_revision, 
       A.purchase_order_date, 
       P.due_date, 
       Nvl(TL.relative_amount, 100) * ( 100 / Nvl(T.base_amount, 100) ), 
       T.name, 
       A.bill_to_customer_id, 
       A.bill_to_contact_id, 
       A.bill_to_site_use_id, 
       U_BILL.location                                        BILL_TO_LOCATION, 
       Nvl(A_BILL.translated_customer_name, PARTY.party_name) BILL_CUST_NAME, 
       Rtrim(Rpad(LOC.address1, 40)), 
       Rtrim(Rpad(LOC.address2, 40)), 
       Rtrim(Rpad(LOC.address3, 40)), 
       Rtrim(Rpad(LOC.address4, 40)), 
       LOC.city, 
       Nvl(LOC.state, LOC.province), 
       LOC.postal_code, 
       LOC.country, 
       U_BILL.tax_reference, 
       PARTY.tax_reference, 
       Nvl(amount_line_items_original, To_number(NULL)), 
       Nvl(tax_original, To_number(NULL)), 
       Nvl(freight_original, To_number(NULL)), 
       p.amount_due_original, 
       A.trx_number, 
       LOC.address1, 
       LOC.address2, 
       LOC.address3, 
       LOC.address4, 
       LOC.state, 
       LOC.province 
FROM   ra_terms_lines TL, 
       ra_cust_trx_types TYPES, 
       ar_lookups L_TYPES, 
       hz_cust_accounts B, 
       hz_parties PARTY, 
       hz_cust_site_uses U_BILL, 
       hz_cust_acct_sites A_BILL, 
       hz_party_sites PARTY_SITE, 
       hz_locations LOC, 
       ar_adjustments COM_ADJ, 
       ra_customer_trx A, 
       ar_payment_schedules P, 
       ra_terms T 
WHERE  A.bill_to_customer_id = B.cust_account_id 
       AND P.payment_schedule_id 
           + Decode(P.class, 'INV', 0, '') = COM_ADJ.payment_schedule_id(+) 
       AND COM_ADJ.subsequent_trx_id IS NULL 
       AND 'C' = COM_ADJ.adjustment_type(+) 
       AND A.complete_flag = 'Y' 
       AND A.customer_trx_id = P.customer_trx_id 
       AND A.cust_trx_type_id = TYPES.cust_trx_type_id 
       AND L_TYPES.lookup_type = 'INV/CM/ADJ' 
       AND A.printing_option IN ( 'PRI', 'REP' ) 
       AND L_TYPES.lookup_code = Decode(TYPES.TYPE, 'DEP', 'INV',TYPES.TYPE) 
       AND Nvl(T.printing_lead_days, 0) > 0 
       AND A.bill_to_site_use_id = U_BILL.site_use_id 
       AND U_BILL.cust_acct_site_id = A_BILL.cust_acct_site_id 
       AND A_BILL.party_site_id = PARTY_SITE.party_site_id 
       AND B.party_id = PARTY.party_id 
       AND LOC.location_id = PARTY_SITE.location_id 
       AND Nvl(LOC.LANGUAGE, 'US') = 'US' 
       AND Nvl(P.terms_sequence_number, TL.sequence_num) = TL.sequence_num 
       AND Nvl(P.amount_due_remaining, 0) <> 0 
       AND T.term_id = P.term_id 
       AND TL.term_id(+) = T.term_id 
       AND A.printing_pending = 'Y' 
       AND P.terms_sequence_number > Nvl(A.last_printed_sequence_num, 0) 
       AND Nvl(LOC.LANGUAGE, 'US') = 'US' 
       AND NOT EXISTS 
       (SELECT 'X' 
           FROM   ece_tp_details ETD, 
                  ece_tp_headers ETH 
           WHERE  ETH.tp_header_id = A_BILL.tp_header_id 
                  AND ETD.tp_header_id = ETH.tp_header_id 
                  AND ETD.edi_flag = 'Y' 
                  AND ETD.document_id = 'INO' 
                  AND ETD.document_type = Decode (TYPES.TYPE, 'CM',Decode(A.previous_customer_trx_id,NULL, 'OACM','CM'),TYPES.TYPE))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please help me how to add Explain Plan file here?

Comment: could any one please help me?

Comment: Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Hi experts can u please help me on this?